# Stacking Boxes 9.10 in Cracking the coding interview

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I spent two hours on this question

You have a stack of n boxes, with widths wi, heights hi, and depths di. The boxes cannot be rotated and can only be stacked on top of one another if each box in the stack larger than or equal to the box above it in width, height, and depth. Implement a method to build the tallest stack possible, where the height of a stack is the sum of the heights of each box.

The idea for the solution is that we try every possible box as a bottom and so the solution is the maximum of (box1 as a bottom, box2 as a bottom and so on). The author has the code for just the main method in which we get the maximum stack given a given bottom

```
vector<Box> createStack(vector<Box> boxes, Box bottom, unordered_map<Box, vector<Box>, BoxHasher> map)
```

Don't we need to add another method in which we call the above method for all the boxes available to us? the author doesn't mention it in the solution.
The method I want to add is

```
vector<Box> createStackMain(vector<Box> boxes)
```

where we try the main method for every possible box

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std; // because this is an example

class Box {
public:
    int d;
    int w;
    int h;
    Box(int d, int w, int h) {
        this->d = d;
        this->w = w;
        this->h = h;
    }
    bool canBeAbove(Box *other) {
        printf("comparing %d %d %d to %d %d %d\n", d, w, h, other->d, other->w, other->h);
        return (d < other->d && w < other->w && h < other->h);
    }
    bool operator==(const Box &other) const {
        return (h == other.h && d == other.d && w == other.w);
    }
};

struct BoxHasher {
    std::size_t operator()(const Box& k) const {
        std::hash<std::string> hashFuction;
        return ((hashFuction(to_string(k.h)) ^ (hashFuction(to_string(k.d)) ^ (hashFuction(to_string(k.w)) << 1)) >> 1));
    }
};

int stackHeight(vector<Box> stack) {
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
        height += stack[i].h;
    }
    return height;
}

vector<Box> createStack(vector<Box> boxes, Box bottom, unordered_map<Box, vector<Box>, BoxHasher> map) {
    if (map.count(bottom) > 0) {
        return map[bottom];
    }
    int max_height = 0;
    vector<Box> max_stack;

    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
        if (boxes[i].canBeAbove(&bottom)) {
            printf("yes\n");
            std::vector<Box> new_stack = createStack(boxes, boxes[i], map);
            int new_height = stackHeight(new_stack);
            if (new_height > max_height) {
                max_height = new_height;
                max_stack = new_stack;
            }
        }
    }
    if (max_stack.size() == 0) {
        max_stack = std::vector<Box>();
    }
    max_stack.push_back(bottom);
    printf("pushing to the max stack %d\n", bottom.h);
    std::reverse(max_stack.begin(), max_stack.end());
    map[bottom] = max_stack;
    return max_stack;
}

// missing method MAX = MAX(BOX1 as a bottom, BOX2 as a bottom and so on)
vector<Box> createStackMain(vector<Box> boxes) {
    vector<Box> max_stack;
    int max_height = 0;
    unordered_map<Box, vector<Box>, BoxHasher> map;
    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
        vector<Box> new_stack = createStack(boxes, boxes[i], map);
        int new_height = stackHeight(new_stack);
        if (new_height > max_height) {
            max_height = new_height;
            max_stack = new_stack;
        }
    }
    return max_stack;
}

int main() {
    vector<Box> boxes;
    boxes.push_back(Box(1, 1, 3));
    boxes.push_back(Box(2, 1, 4));
    boxes.push_back(Box(4, 2, 1));
    boxes.push_back(Box(6, 7, 7));
    vector<Box> max = createStackMain(boxes);
    printf("%d\n", stackHeight(max));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a greedy approach would work.

Comment: @mhcuervo as described above, no boxes can sit on top of a zero height box.

Comment: @TavianBarnes you mean the tallest box that would currently work?  That won't work -- have a pile of nearly-same-sized boxes, and one box that is extremely narrow and tall.  The narrow/tall one is picked greedily, but the other boxes would be a better choice.

Comment: @Yakk No, pick the box that maximizes `min(width, height, depth)`

Comment: With the question, couldn't you just sort the boxes based on the volume and that becomes your stack?

Comment: @Yakk Never mind, that wouldn't work.  It would maximize the number of boxes, not the height of the tower.

Comment: @TavianBarnes *nod*, tall and skinny can still be taller than a medium sized square.  So 5x5x5 then a 2x2x2 vs a 1x1x4 -- your algorithm picks 2x2x2, while 1x1x4 is taller.  The way I'd approach this would be to start with a 1 dimensional problem (easy -- greedy works), then the 2 dimensional problem (where greedy doesn't work), and then see if it generalizes to 3 dimensional at all.